# how to move image using UIAccelerometer?

Tags: iphone

How to move image when i am moving iphone?

Comment: i don't think you'll get an answer unless you elaborate and accept previous answers

Answer (score 0):

THis question really needs to be improved.  Your best bet would be to look at [UIAccelerometer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/Reference/UIAccelerometer.html) and [UIImage documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  If you provide more details of what you want to do, I can provide a more detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as zPesk said, read docs. But, as an approximation.

Start accelerometer setting your class as the *sharedAccelerometer* delegate. Then implement *accelerometer:didAccelerate:* on your class and check the X and Y axis (if you want to move the image on 2D).

If X axis is negative, move your image to the left, if positive to the right. If Y axis is negative, to the bottom, if positive, to the top.

If you want to accelerate the movement of the image depending on the measurement of the accelerometer, multiply some pixel constant for the axis measurement and add it to the X and Y of the frame of the image. The more you tilt the device, the more accelerated is the movement.